# How to configure a remote webdriver in Nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, remotewebdriver, nightwatch, selenoid

I'm getting started with Nightwatch and trying to launch a browser remotely using Selenoid.

But looks like there is no sample of remote Webdriver configuration in official documentation.
For instance, in Java I'm creating a RemoteWebdriver object, passing the hub url into it, like:

```
 WebDriver wd = new RemoteWebDriver(URI.create('http://hub-master:4444/wd/hub').toURL(), capabilities)
```

But when I'm setting the suggested parameters from the documentation (https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/#webdriver-settings):

```
webdriver: {
        "host": "http://hub-master",
        "port": 4444,
        "default_path_prefix": "/wd/hub",
        "log_path": 'selenium_logs',
},
```

I'm getting the error:

```
  An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://simulia-master"
```

So could anyone provide an example of configured remote webdriver in Nightwatch conf.js for Selenoid or Selenium Grid, please?

Comment: I think should be just `hub-master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by the following configuration.
It appeared that basic `selenium` settings can be set in `default` to be used for several local environments, and also, its particular fields like host and port can be overridden in `selenoid` environments:

```
 test_settings: {
        default: {
            disable_error_log: false,
            launch_url: 'https://my-url.com',
            selenium: {
                host: "localhost",
                port: 4444,
                start_process: true,
                server_path: "node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar",
                start_session: true,
                log_path: "out/selenium_log",
                cli_args: {
                    "webdriver.chrome.driver": "node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe",
                    "webdriver.gecko.driver": "node_modules/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe"
                }
            },
            desiredCapabilities: {
                "browserName": "chrome", /* default browser for local run */
            },
        },
        chrome: {
            silent: true,
            screenshots: {
                enabled: true,
                path: './screenshots/chrome/',
                on_failure: true,
                on_error: true,
            },
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: "chrome",
                chromeOptions: {
                    args: [
                        "disable-web-security",
                        "ignore-certificate-errors",
                        "--test-type"
                    ],
                    "prefs": {
                        "protocol_handler": {
                            "allowed_origin_protocol_pairs": allowedProtocols
                        },
                    },
                    "w3c": false,
                }
            }
        },
        firefox: {
            screenshots: {
                enabled: true,
                path: './screenshots/firefox/',
                on_failure: true,
                on_error: true,
            },
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: "firefox",
                alwaysMatch: {
                    "moz:firefoxOptions": {
                        args: [
                            "--headless",
                            "--width=1920",
                            "--height=1080"
                        ],
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        selenoidChrome: {
            selenium: {
                start_process: false,
                host: "selenoid-host",
                port: 4444,
                live_output: true,
            },
            screenshots: {
                enabled: true,
                path: './screenshots/selenoidChrome',
                on_failure: true,
                on_error: true,
            },
            desiredCapabilities: {
                "enableVNC": true,
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "enableLog": true,
                "enableVideo": true,
            },
        },
        selenoidFirefox: {
            extends: 'selenoidChrome',
            screenshots: {
                path: './screenshots/selenoidFirefox',
            },
            desiredCapabilities: {
                "browserName": "firefox",
            }
        },
    },
```